# va_argv принцип работы

Tags: c, стек

есть кусок функции с переменным числом параметров и ее вызов

```
number(1, 15, 58, 89, 78, 8, -1, 578, 483);
```

..........

```
unsigned int number(unsigned int i, ...) {                          /*it doesn't work*/
va_list element;
va_start(element, i);
while (*element != -1) {
    printf("%d\n", *element);
    va_arg(element, unsigned int);
}
va_end(element);
```

почему первым элементом у меня идет 15, а не 1?
это какие-то особенности макроса или все дело в стеке?

Comment: *Что именно* вы распечатываете? И мне кажется, что вы неправильно используете `va_arg()`. Вообще-то он возвращает значение, с которым вы и должны работать. У вас же это функция просто вызывается сама по себе.

Comment: Если же вы пытаетесь распечатать `element` после первого `va_arg()`, то неудивительно, что указатель `va_list` сдвинулся и стал указывать уже на второй элемент.

Comment: @Arhad с va_arg() понятно, а   с va_start что? мне нужен доступ ко всем элементам, переданных  у функцию. я написал просто участок кода для демонстрации. здесь отчет начинается со второго аргумента.

Comment: У вас есть доступ ко всем аргументам, переданным в функцию. Просто первый аргумент доступен через i, а остальные - через va_arg.

Comment: @o2gy  теперь понятно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас в коде написана какая-то некорректная белиберда, поэтому пытаться объяснять его поведение бессмысленно.

1. Никто вам не разрешал применять оператор `*` к `va_list element` и вообще делать какие-то предположения о типе или значении выражения `*element`. Поэтому ваше

   ```
   while (*element != -1) {
   ```

   и

   ```
   printf("%d\n", *element);
   ```

   это полная бессмыслица. Откуда у вас вообще возникла идея делать что-то подобное?

   Вам вообще не разрешается работать с `element` напрямую. Все, что вы можете делать с `element` - это передавать его в макросы группы `va_...`.
2. Доступ к `...` параметрам производится через `va_arg` и больше никак. То есть очередной аргумент - это *результат* `va_arg`. У вас же в коде результат `va_arg` вообще не используется.

   Попутно `va_arg` переставляет `va_list` на следующий параметр в последовательности `...`.
3. Именно так и работают `va_start`/`va_arg` - они дают вам доступ к первому из `...` аргументов, затем второму и т.д. То есть первым вы должны получить именно `15`.

   К именованному аргументу `i` вы через эти макросы доступ не получите и не должны получать. К нему у вас и так есть доступ по имени `i`.

Правильное использование этих макросов в вашем случае может выглядеть так

```
unsigned int number(unsigned int i, ...) 
{ 
  va_list element;
  va_start(element, i);

  do
  {
    int p = va_arg(element, int);
    if (p == -1)
      break;

    printf("%d\n", p);
  } while (1);

  va_end(element);

  /* return ... */
}
```

Непонятно только, чего вы хотели добиться вашей мешаниной из знаковых и беззнаковых типов.

Answer (score 3):

Это особенности va_list...
Попробуйте распечатать i :)

PS: первый аргумент доступен через i, остальные - через va_arg.
Более того, можно написать и так:

```
void number(int i, int j, ...) {
    va_start(element, j);
```

Тогда va_arg начнет "доставать" из стека, начиная с третьего аргумента.

Comment: Получается, мы указываем в `va_start` последний фиксированный аргумент. А как быть, если функция вообще не имеет фиксированных аргументов (по типу сишных пустых скобок в прототипе фукции)?

Comment: По-моему без фиксированных элементов нельзя. По крайней мере макрос `va_start` ожидает 2 аргумента.

Comment: @Arhad, устаревший набор макросов из [varargs.h](http://osr507doc.sco.com/man/html.S/varargs.S.html) позволяет. Также можете посмотреть пример в [man stdarg](https://linux.die.net/man/3/stdarg). / И кстати, в некотрых система аргументы передаются не в стеке, а в регистрах. В этом случае обычно они копируются во вспомогательную память, откуда затем и выбираются